# graph representation through adjacency lists using STL in c++

Tags: c++, list, vector, graph, stl

I am trying to represent a graph through adjacency list in c++. As of now i just want to print the vertices to which a given vertex is attached. I am doing this through vectors and lists. Following is the code

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include <vector>
  #include <list>
  using namespace std;
  const int N=4;

  int main()
  {
    std::vector <std::list<int> > adjList(N);

    adjList[0].push_back(1);

    adjList[0].push_back(2);

    adjList[1].push_back(2);
    adjList[1].push_back(0);

    adjList[2].push_back(0);
    adjList[2].push_back(1);
    adjList[2].push_back(3);

    adjList[3].push_back(2);

    std::vector<std::list<int> >::iterator i;

    int c=0;
    for (std::vector<std::list<int> >::iterator i = adjList.begin(); i != adjList.end(); ++i)
    {
      cout<<"vertices connected to node "<< c <<"are";
      std::list<int> li=*i;
      for (std::list<int>::iterator iter=li.begin(); iter!=li.end();++iter)
      {
        cout<<*iter<<" ";
      }
      cout<<endl;
      c++;
    }
    return(0);
  }
```

The code is compiling fine, but is not giving any output. I am using code blocks and GNU GCC, C++ 98 compiler to compile my code.

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't magically resize itself on demand. You need to explicitly add elements to it before you can modify or reference them.

Comment: but am i not doing that when i write push_back followed by the elements in brackets. i am new to this so can you elaborate a little more

Comment: `adjList` has no elements and zero size. `adjList[0]` does not exist. You cannot refer to it. Doing so is undefined behavior. You need to add elements to `adjList` first.

Comment: @n.m. `adjList` is being constructed with length `N=4`.

Comment: @asdfg I was able to build and run your code with g++4.7.2 on a linux terminal. It prints the output just fine. Perhaps it has something to do with your CodeBlocks config?

Comment: @Pradhan oops, sorry, missed that. my eyes are no good :(

Comment: got mine to run too just restarted my code blocks i dont know what was happening there probably making a stupid mistake or something thanks anyways

Answer (score -1):

Use post increment operator for loop counters 'i' and 'iter'.